# what are the argument inside the libfuse callbacks?

Tags: c++, fuse

I was trying to make a simple file system using libfuse on my linux using tutorial -> https://engineering.facile.it/blog/eng/write-filesystem-fuse/

But i couldn't able to undersand some particular things.

```
static int read_callback(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
    struct fuse_file_info *fi)
```

1 . In this read_callback function `buf` is the buffer which contains the actual data of file , `fi` is a special struct which contains information about file

what is offset here ?

```
  if (offset + size > len) {
      memcpy(buf, filecontent + offset, len - offset);
      return len - offset;
    }
```

from above code , it is clear that we are trying to read the file using `memcpy` , but what will be the value of offsey in each call .

what is path here ?

https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/callbacks.html
here it is mentioned that , the path is relative to mount point. 
Can someone elaborate on it ?

Thanks in advance